# How to get which video card(nvdia or amd) is using in DirectX

Tags: directx, direct3d, amd-processor

I need to know how to get which kind of video card is using in directX, because some features in my program are not supported in amd video card and cause crash.

So, I need to get which card the computer is using(some computer may have more than one video card).

Comment: What OS are you using? What version of Direct3D?

Answer (score 2):

So before you throw ATI/AMD [under the bus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Throw_under_the_bus) here, make sure that the problem is not actually due to your application. For Direct3D 10/11, be sure to enable the [debug device](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/11/30/direct3d-sdk-debug-layer-tricks.aspx) and ensure you do not have any CORRUPTION or ERRORS, and look at all WARNINGS.

Next, see if there is a newer driver available for the repro case. If there is, then just tell your users to update their drivers. If not, and it seems to be a legitimate crash inside the driver then report that as a bug to ATI/AMD (or NVidia or Intel as the case may be).

Test your app on more than one video card/driver combination from each vendor. For indies this can be challenging, but it's an important part of making sure your application works on a broad set of hardware. For Direct3D 11, you need to try various Direct3D [hardware feature level](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/06/20/direct3d-feature-levels.aspx) devices to ensure good coverage.

Real games do have some extra warnings tied to detecting specific hardware IDs when dealing with wide-spread driver bugs and unofficial vendor-specific extensions). There is an example of doing this detection [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2014/02/05/anatomy-of-direct3d-11-create-device.aspx) based on the vendorid/deviceid combination in `DXGI_ADAPTER_DESC` or `D3DADAPTER_IDENTIFIER9`. Locking out all cards from a specific vendor is overkill and likely to just annoy your customers.

Comment: I used the VTF in DirectX 9 and ATI/AMD does not support VTF in shader model 3.0.

Comment: You do not need a vendor check for this. Use ``CheckDeviceFormat`` with ``D3DUSAGE_QUERY_VERTEXTEXTURE``. You will find that no format is supported for the problem cards. It's actually not valid to use a format as a vertex texture without validating it this way for shader model 3.0. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb206339.aspx). Vertex texture formats are of course required for Shader Model 4.0 or later devices (aka Direct3D feature level 10.0+). As such, most newer ATI/AMD actually do support vertex textures and ``CheckDeviceFormat`` will discover that.